# Django model aggregate function returns different result in shell and in request endpoint

Tags: python, django

Django version: 4.2.4
Python version: 3.10.8

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db.models.aggregates import Max
from .models.product import Product

def product_page(request):
    agg = Product.objects.aaggregate(max__price=Max('price'))

    return render(request, 'product.html', {'max_price': agg['max__price']}
```

I get following error when reading the result from `agg` :

```
'coroutine' object is not subscriptable
```

But, when I run the same code in django shell I get the expected result in `dict`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my heavens. I was calling async method `aaggregate` [double a]  on a queryset. For that reason I was getting a `Coroutine` instead of a dict. I could simply call `aggregate` on a queryset object to get the desired result.

PS: It was all because of autocomplete from VSCode .

The solution is to use a sync method instead of async.

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db.models.aggregates import Max
from .models.product import Product

def product_page(request):
    agg = Product.objects.aggregate(max__price=Max('price'))

    return render(request, 'product.html', {'max_price': agg['max__price']}
```